# Obtain pairs of nodes having exactly one relationship of a certain type which connects them to each other in Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a graph database in Neo4j with drugs and drug-drug interactions, among other entities. In this regard, `()-[:IS_PARTICIPANT_IN]->()` connects a drug to an interaction. I need to obtain those pairs of drugs `a` and `b` which are not involved in any other `:IS_PARTICIPANT_IN` relationship other than the one between them, i.e. `(a)-[:IS_PARTICIPANT_IN]->(ddi:DrugDrugInteraction)<-[:IS_PARTICIPANT_IN]-(b)`, without any other `IS_PARTICIPANT_IN` relationships involving neither `a` nor `b`.

For that purpose, I have tried the following Cypher query. However, it ends up reaching heap size (raised to 8 GB), as collect operations consume too much memory.

```
MATCH (drug1:Drug)-[r1:IS_PARTICIPANT_IN]->(ddi:DrugDrugInteraction)
MATCH (drug2:Drug)-[r2:IS_PARTICIPANT_IN]->(ddi)
WHERE drug1 <> drug2 
OPTIONAL MATCH (drug2)-[r3:IS_PARTICIPANT_IN]->(furtherDDI:DrugDrugInteraction)
WHERE furtherDDI <> ddi
WITH drug1, drug2, ddi, COLLECT(ddi) AS ddis, furtherDDI, COLLECT(furtherDDI) AS additionalDDIs
WITH drug1, drug2, ddi, COUNT(ddis) AS n1, COUNT(additionalDDIs) AS n2
WHERE n1 = 1 AND n2 = 0
RETURN drug1.name, drug2.name, ddi.name ORDER BY drug1;
```

How can I improve my code so as to get the desired results without exceeding the heap size limit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
MATCH (d:Drug)
WHERE SIZE((d)-[:IS_PARTICIPANT_IN]->()) = 1
MATCH (d)-[:IS_PARTICIPANT_IN]->(ddi)
RETURN ddi.name AS ddiName, COLLECT(d.name) AS drugNames
ORDER BY drugNames[0]
```

The `WHERE` clause uses a very efficient degreeness check to filter for `Drug` nodes that have only a single outgoing `IS_PARTICIPANT_IN` relationship. This check is efficient because it does not have to actually get any `DrugDrugInteraction` nodes.

After the degreeness check, the query performs a second `MATCH` to actually get the associated `DrugDrugInteraction` node. (I assume that the `IS_PARTICIPANT_IN` relationship only points at `DrugDrugInteraction` nodes, and have therefore omitted the label from the search pattern, for efficiency).

The `RETURN` clause uses the [aggregating function](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/aggregating/) `COLLECT` to collect the `Drug` names for each `ddi` name. (I assume that `ddi` nodes have unique names.)

By the way, this query will also work if there are any number of `Drug`s (not just 2) that participate in the same `DrugDrugInteraction`, and no other ones. Also, if a matched `DrugDrugInteraction` happens to have a related `Drug` that participates in other interactions, this query will not include that `Drug` in the result (since this query only pays attention to `d` nodes that passed the initial degreeness check).